How can I remotely trigger an alarm on a friend's phone (with permission)
I have a friend who has a bad habit of sleeping in. Usually we talk in the mornings, but if they don't message me, they want me to wake them up. We could just phone call or use chat apps to initiate a call, but we're really looking for an app that might possibly have other features related to alarms and long distance. With millions of apps out there, surely one of them will meet our needs.
I have looked into using calendars with alarms, but those seem to be limited to a 15 minute sync cycle. If they need to be woken up, a potential 15 minutes until it syncs seems bad!

Presumably your friend is on iOS, because if he's on Android this won't be the place to get help :). Anyway, I'm unsure about apps, but I wonder if your friend could create a automation that triggers each time he receives a message from you that explicitly says "Wake up!"? Creating this automation is easy in the Shortcuts app, but you/he will need to do some research on creating a shortcut that triggers the alarm after the automation is triggered... I don't know how to do that, but at least you have a starting point. Good luck! :)

Yes, it is tagged [tag:iphone] - I do not know what version of iOS they are on. I personally am on android but there has to be something out there with a web interface.
